# Import private Album from Google Photos using "Picasa Web Albums Data API" in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-photos

Does anyone having an idea how can I import Photos from Google Photos?

I get some information that I need to you Picasa Web Album API. I have referred developer forum but I didn't get any  details!